# Удалить отправленный объект?

Tags: javascript

Как в fetch удалить object на success и error тут после отправки?

```
const list = {};

function myLogger(error) {
    if (!(error instanceof Error)) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    const object = JSON.stringify({
        param1: 'param1',
        param2: 'param2'
    });

    if (list[object]) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    list[object] = true;

    return fetch('someurl', {
        object
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {

        if (res.resultCode !== 'OK') {
            throw new Error(res.errorMessage);
        }
        return res;
    }).then(здесь нужно удалять object отправленный);
}
```

Comment: Воспользоваться оператором `delete object;` - или выставить `null`.

Comment: .then(object === null)
.catch(object === null)

таким образом?

Comment: нужно на success и error

Comment: object недступен же в then

Comment: нужно после отправки чистить перменную,чтобы избежать утечки

Comment: .then(  на success и error нужно добавить удаление отправленного object );

Comment: .then(() => delete  list[object]).catch(() => delete list[object]); так?

Comment: Проверьте после обработки `myLogger`  напишите `console.log(list);` и посмотрите, что будет. Старайтесь отлаживать свой код. или использовать дебагер, там все есть у него.